# SQL Injections using Jfactory::getDBO and setQuery() with LIKE condition

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, jdatabase, sql, joomla3.8.5

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$searchP = JRequest::getVar('key');
$sql = "SELECT name FROM people LIKE " . "'%" . $searchP . "%'";

$db->setQuery($sql);
$fileR = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Will setQuery() throw an error for having two SQL statements in the same string?

For example, according to my code, is it possible to execute a drop table command by passing this query parameter or something similar:

```
key=a'; DROP TABLE people; #
```

Furthermore will using something like

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query ->setLimit('1');
$query ->select($db->quoteName('name'));
$query ->from($db->quoteName('people'));
$query ->like($db->quoteName($searchP));
$db->setQuery($query);
```

prevent injection since the query object's query limit is being set to 1?

Comment: Where did you find that `->like()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't need to worry about sql injection attacks if you use the `quote()` ( or `q()`) and `quoteName()` (or `qn()`) methods appropriately.

From https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Secure_on_search

> **Secure on search**

> Special attention should be paid to LIKE clauses
> which contain the % wildcard character as these require special
> escaping in order to avoid possible denial of service attacks. LIKE
> clauses can be handled like this:
>
> // Construct the search term by escaping the user-supplied string and,
> if required, adding the % wildcard characters manually.

```
$search = '%' . $db->escape( $search, true ) . '%' );
```

> // Construct the SQL query, being careful to suppress the default
> behaviour of Quote so as to prevent double-escaping.

```
$query = 'SELECT  * FROM #__table WHERE `field` LIKE ' . $db->quote( $search, false );
```

`->like()`, as far as I have researched, doesn't exist. So, based on the above documentation recommendation and assuming you want to search the `name` column, I'll suggest the following code block:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->qn('name'))
            ->from($db->qn('people'))
            ->where($db->qn('name') . ' LIKE ' . $db->q('%' . $db->escape($searchP, true) . '%', false));
$db->setQuery($query);
```

When performing a `LIKE` query it is often logical to receive multiple rows of data in the resultset.  Since I believe you were merely using the `setLimit()` method as a security precaution, I'll remove it for the sake of improved querying.

---

[A relevant post from Lodder from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374054/2943403) regarding prepared statements in Joomla.

The intent/effect of quote(escape()) method in my code block above is to ensure that no matter what string is passed to the query, the string is always treated as a single value in the expression.

---

From Joomla4, `bind()` can be used in conjunction with a placeholder.  The previously scripted query can simplified to:

```
$searchLike = "%$searchP%"; // declare search value wrapped in wildcard characters

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->qn('name'))
            ->from($db->qn('people'))
            ->where($db->qn('name') . ' LIKE :search')
            ->bind(':search', $searchLike);
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Note that the bound value must be declared as a variable in advance.

Comment: My understanding is that using string escaping will just prevent php from being executed (because it is just making sure that the user input is treated as a string and is properly escaped). If I pass a string with a semi colon and add another sql command after that, wouldn't the query I pass to mysql execute that either way? Could you briefly explain how string escaping would prevent injection?

Comment: @JayShri I've extended my answer to address your comment.  String escaping protects against injection by ensuring any malicious / single-quote carrying string is merely treated as a string value that is wrapped in single quotes.  This is important for non-malicious strings as well, like the name `Padraic O'Neil` which can compromise a query if the the mid-string `'` is not escaped.

Comment: This is good, but I realized another important aspect is making sure your input is good. Before checking to escape strings.  `$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;  $q = $jinput->get('search', '', 'WORD');` This will remove characters other than characters z-a and underscore.

Comment: @mickmackusa I get the following error _:bind(): Argument #2 ($value) cannot be passed by reference_. Solved If wildcards are included in a line before: `$searchP = "%$searchP%";` and `->bind(':search', $searchP);`

Comment: @Peli whoops, thanks. Fixed.