# Query gives a single value when two columns in SELECT clause

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, jdatabase

I do have a database connection earlier in the script.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

Here's the query code:

```
$albumartistidquery = $db->getQuery(true);

$albumartistidquery->select($db->quoteName(array('artist_id', 'artist_name')));
$albumartistidquery->from($db->quoteName('#__vinylvault_artists'));
$albumartistidquery->lookup($db->quoteName('artist_name'));
$albumartistidquery->where($db->quoteName('artist_id') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($releaseartistid));

$db->setQuery($albumartistidquery);

// Load the results
$dbalbumartist = $db->loadResult();
```

I'm expecting that `$dbalbumartist` should contain the contents of the relevant `'artist_name'` field, but when I echo `$dbalbumartist` it displays the `artist_id` column value.

Can anyone advise where I've gone wrong and how to fix?

Comment: You like clause value is incorrect. Check the documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Hi Charlie @Lodder strange how the same structure works fine on numerous other queries in the same component that I'm writing.  the $releaseartistid variable is delated and populated previously in the script

Comment: Note the `%` symbol

Comment: % there is no % in that code snippet Charlie @Lodder

Comment: Also, you're using `->lookup()`. Where in the API section did you see this? I've never heard of it.

Comment: Remove the ->lookup line and try it

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, your code is pretty right.  As commented, you are using `->lookup()` -- a method that is currently unheard of.

Generally, you would only use the `LIKE` operator if you were going to also use `_` or `%` wildcard symbols.  Because your `LIKE` condition is matching the whole `$releaseartistid` string, it seems more logical to replace `LIKE` with `=`.

The [loadResult()](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Single_Value_Result) method is to be used when you are only expecting a single value in the resultset.  Your query is returning two columns of data so if you are expecting a single row of data, then you might prefer `loadRow()`, `loadAssoc()`, or `loadObject()`.  If your resultset may contain more than one row of data, then refer to the [Mult-Row Methods](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Multi-Row_Results) and determine which method is best suited for your project.

Assuming your `$releaseartistid` value is an integer, you can avoid quote-wrapping the value and maintain security by casting the value as `(int)`.

As a matter of personal preference, I use `qn()` versus `quoteName()` purely for code brevity.

Suggested Code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $albumartistidquery = $db->getQuery(true)
                             ->select($db->qn(array('artist_id', 'artist_name')))
                             ->from($db->qn('#__vinylvault_artists'))
                             ->where($db->qn('artist_id') . ' = ' . (int)$releaseartistid);
    echo $albumartistidquery->dump();    // never expose this on your live/public site
    $db->setQuery($albumartistidquery);
    echo "<pre>";
        var_export($db->loadAssoc());  // display the resultset
    echo "</pre>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<div>", $e->getMessage(), "</div>";  // never expose this on your live/public site
}
```

Finally, if you DO want to use `LIKE` with wildcards, I'll refer you to this post where I explain [how to use `LIKE` with proper Joomla escaping syntax to maintain query security](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352).