# How to match database values regardless of accents on letters?

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, unicode

With the following LIKE condition in my WHERE clause, I only get the exact match.

```
. ' LIKE '. $db->quote($db->escape($artist)), 'AND') .
```

When `$artist` is, for example `Beyoncé`, it only returns a value when `$artist` is exactly `Beyoncé`.

I want it to return a value as well when the database value is `Beyonce`.

I found solutions where there is no variable (something with `%`), but I can't get this to work.

Comment: Initially I thought you wanted this: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352 , but now I see that you don't want `LIKE`, you want to allow accented or non-accented letters to qualify.  Do you have a short list (perhaps 4 or 5 different values that express the scope of this issue) of realistic values so that a fully resolving recommendation can be made? Does your Joomla site have a primary language or is it multilingual? What is the charset and collation of your table? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10023776/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/37665452/2943403

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190975/157408 ,https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/122607/157408 Otherwise, if you are unable or unwilling to modify your database settings, you could use some convoluted REGEX or create a new column in your table that has all of the accented character pre-reduced to their relative single-byte form and only make search queries that also have multibyte characters reduced to single-byte characters.  I think we'll need some feedback from you.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 - Store additional column

First method is to store additional column in your artists table with only a latin characters in it (eg. `beyonce`).

### Method 2 - Update the LIKE query

MySQL have the ability to replace exacly one character with a wildcard. In your case the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `#__artists` 
WHERE `artist` LIKE "beyonc_"
```

This query would match:

- Beyoncé
- Beyonce
- Beyonci
- Beyonct

But would not match:

- Beyonc
- Beyoncee
- Beyoncét

### Method 3 - Use a full text search

Last method is to use [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). It would require some changes in table. The columns you try to match against would need to be of type `Text`. Then you can run a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `#__artists` 
WHERE 
    MATCH (`artist`) AGAINST ('Beyonce' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

This should return all the results that match a string.

Alternatively you can provide a score column like this:

```
SELECT 
    *, MATCH (`artist`) AGAINST ('Beyonce' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS `score` 
FROM `#__artists` 
WHERE `score`>0
```

and decide what results are best by checking `score` column. To read more about full text search click the link above.