# Using Like with wildcard in joomla php query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla-4.x

Hi I am struggling to get an output from a wildcard query.
I am using the following code which outputs the following error:

> 0 Unknown format specifier "$"

```
$iban = 'IE04IBPSIE123456123456123456';
//split array into chunks of 4 chars
$iban = str_split($iban,4);
//print_r($iban);
$iban = $iban[1];

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db
    ->getQuery(true)
    ->select('bic')
    ->from($db->quoteName('aaa_bic'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('bic') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%'. $iban . '%'));


$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

return $result;
```

For the example i replaced $iban with a dummy value.
The code should get the "IBPS" bit out of the iban and compare it with the bic code that matches and return the relevant bic code
var_dump($result);
exit;
Gives Null
How do i correctly use Like '%$iban%' in joomla query please?

Comment: I expect that you'll find [SQL Injections using Jfactory::getDBO and setQuery() with LIKE condition](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352) enlightening.  I also recommend that you use `substr($iban, 4, 4)` instead of creating an array with `str_split()` then only accessing the second element with `[1]`.  If you have a more fundamental SQL problem, I cannot assist because I cannot see your database table structure/data.

Comment: It doesn't look like the error is coming from this piece of code. You should enable debug and inspect the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the code to use: `substr($iban, 4, 4)` and updated my query to `->where($db->qn('bic') . ' LIKE ' . $db->q('%' . $db->escape($iban, true) . '%', false));` the var_dump($result); shows **string(8) "IPBSIE2D"** which is correct, however when i replace with `return $result;` i get the error **0 Unknown format specifier " "** on form submission. FYI I'm using fabrik4 and joomla4.2.5 with php8.1